# Reload an Activity when a notification arrives, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android app that need to change the interface when a push notification arrives,

Example:

User start the Activity A, then He goes to Activity B.
While User is reading a text in Activity B,a Push notification arrives, the text in Activity B should change and the text in Activity A should change too.

I can do it on Activity A with `onResume()` but I dont know how to do it in Activity B

Comment: Thanks Marko, but that wont resolve the problem to update the text on Activity B

Comment: Show us the code you are using to open Activity B when the notification arrives.

Comment: The notification dont open the Activity B, The notification should UPDATE the Activity B if the user is on Activity B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GCM sample that comes with the GCM library (in your Android SDK Folder/extras) gives you an example on how to do this:

1. in GCMIntentService onReceive method, they called `displayMessage`, which broadcasts a message after a GCM notification is received.
2. in DemoActivity::onCreate, they register a receiver to handle the broadcast message.
3. the onReceive method of the broadcast receiver `mHandleMessageReceiver` performs the UI update.

Comment: @D4rWiNS Where did you find the Sample? I have been unable to find it!

Comment: I found it in the sdk folder ( where you have installed eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to receive updates when notification arrives then you need to implement Broadcast Receiver. You need to register the receiver in onResume and unregister it in onPause.

The place you need to implement to update your text views is the onReceive method of Broadcast listener. You can easily find some examples by searching "Android Broadcast Receiver". Hope it helps.